# Kubuntu 19.10 Wine and Zbrush 2020.1 Disappearing Programs

Tags: kubuntu, wine

We are running Kubuntu 19.10 with the most currant stable version of Wine. We had ZBrush 2020.1 running great. Then we received a message from ZBrush about an update so we did the update. That was a bad idea. Things went crazy.

We then did a fresh install of Kubuntu 19.10 and Wine and Winetricks. We installed the corefronts that are recommended on the appdb on the wine website. We put the ZBrush 2020.1 exe file on the desktop. Then rightclick properties make executible. Then we tried to run with Wine and we received a message that said

A Fatal Error Occured

So we tried the terminal

```
cd Desktop
```

then

```
sudo wine file.exe
```

After this the program started to install. Then opened and seemed to work. We closed the program. We went to the Kubuntu applcation you access from the bottom left corner. No icon there. So we went to Dolphin. Clicked show hidden files. Then

home/.wine/drive_c/Program Files

We checked in the programs File and in the Programs File (×86). The program is not there. If you try to install it agian, the software says it is already installed. We can not find it. We have asked for help everywhere and we are still trying to fix this.

We tried

'locate zbrush'

It will only show a xml file and the exe file on the desktop.

Please help. I had this running and broke it and now I can't fix it.

Comment: The `locate` command is case-sensitive. So `locate zbrush` will not catch `zBrush`. Use `locate -i zbrush` as pointed out already to you [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/76706-kubuntu-and-zbrush-with-wine?p=436079&viewfull=1#post436079).

Comment: I tried that with the same results. It only shows the xml and exe files. The program is not anywhere I can find. Someone on another forum said the same thing to add the -i but it did not help. I am sorry if I sound snappy. I am not trying to. This has been so frustrating. I know it can work. It was before. I don't understand how it can work and now not work doing the same steps as the first time I did this. It just makes no sense.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? If so please share your thoughts.
Thare are some users over at the ZBC who apparently try to get an overall solution to get ZBrush running on Linux:
https://www.zbrushcentral.com/t/using-zbrush-on-linux/351246/51